# Why is this condition not being checked?

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, google-calendar-api, console.log

I am curently working on a small project where I want to check via the google calendar API if a room is busy or not.
For that I use this function:

```
//checking for change of all values. Then console.log values on change and executing request if busy.
function avalabilityCheck() {
    [...inputs].forEach(input => {
            input.addEventListener('change', function () {
                    if (date.value !== "" && startTime.value !== "" && endTime.value !== ""
                    ) {let isBusy = true;
                    //looping through all rooms in compartment
                        for (let key in comp_1) {
                            if (comp_1.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                                let calendarID = comp_1[key];
                                let roomName = key;
                                //console.log(value);
                                //user input that goes into the freebusy query
                                let requestBody = {
                                    timeMin: date.value + "T" + startTime.value + ":00.000Z",
                                    timeMax: date.value + "T" + endTime.value + ":00.000Z",
                                    items: [
                                        {
                                            id: calendarID
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    timeZone: "GMT+01:00"
                                };


                                //make request to gcalendar if rooms are free. Giving back array on what times room is busy.
                                var freeRequest = gapi.client.calendar.freebusy.query(requestBody);

                                //executing request.
                                freeRequest.execute(function (resp) {
                                    var responseObject = JSON.stringify(resp);
                                    console.log(responseObject);
                                    if (resp.calendars[calendarID].busy.length < 1) {
                                        console.log(`${roomName} is free`);
                                    } else { isBusy = false;
                                    console.log("room is Busy");}

                                })

                          }
                        }

                    console.log("finito");
                    if (isBusy === false) {
                        console.log("working?");
                    }
                    else{console.log("not working");}
                    } else {
                        console.log("change date pls");
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    )
}
```

now `let isBusy = true;` and when a room is busy I want isBusy to be false:

```
if (resp.calendars[calendarID].busy.length < 1) {
                                        console.log(`${roomName} is free`);
                                    } else { isBusy = false;
                                    console.log("room is Busy");}
```

So When I run the app the console should either give :

```
console.log("finito");
if (isBusy === false) {
console.log("working?");
 }
else{console.log("not working");}
```

But it only gives "finito" to the console and apparently is not checking the state of isBusy.
Does anyone see what is the Problem here?
Thank you!

Comment: Well, for one, you are setting `isBusy` to `false` when the room is busy (should be `true`). And  you're only setting `isBusy` in one of the two `if` branches which you need to do even though you are initializing `isBusy` because what if `isBusy` gets set by the `if` statement and then later the `if` statement runs again and hits the other branch?>

Comment: If the condition
```if (resp.calendars[calendarID].busy.length < 1) ```
is not fullfilled the else says that ```isBusy``` should be ```false```, or is that incorrect?

Comment: Your code is not well formatted. The indentation of the part around "finito" is not right, and you have statements following on the same line as the opening brace. Important is that the `execute` callback is only executed later. So you will get at "finito" output when none of those callbacks have executed yet.